# How to implement a Oauth 2 mechanism in JavaEE for JSF?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, oauth, javabeans

I'm working a JSF projects with beans and xhtml pages and now I've implemented a import javax.servlet.Filter; with username and password to secure the pages, except, of course, the login.xhtml. Since I want to upgrade the security mechanism, I want to insert the Oauth2 mechanism. How Can I do? I've read some spring implementations, but seems only for REST service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **don't** implement it in JSF, you implement it in a security layer which, at most, gets the username/password or token from the jsf based userinterface. Best is to not implement this from scratch but use a real good existing security framework for this. Something like [Apache Shiro](https://shiro.apache.org/), [JBoss Picketlink](http://picketlink.org/) or the likes, one that can do oauth for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So the idea is to use of these frameworks, but no of them use real oauth. By the way, I can implement my own reminder, with a cookie, that can least one day/week and it may be changed to increase security, isn’t it?

Comment: What do you mean by _"but no of them use real oauth."_? For both of them I find oauth references

Comment: The best working option in my opinion is is using the JavaEE 8 security API. Containers such as Payara already include a OAuthIdentityStore for use with JavaEE 8 that you can take advantage of. You can also combine something like SocialAuth (https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth) with the JavaEE 8 security API and implement your own identity store very easily.

Comment: Good suggestion. I have been stuck in the solutions I mentioned from the times java ee security was sort of not very flexible. please create an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My need it is keep as long as possible the user logged during the times, like Amazon does. I mean, once the user sent username and password, he doesn't need to set them again, just if he logs out or it doesn't come on Amazon for times. How Can I do in the easiest way?